# Hide entire column(s) right of specific column accounting for rowspans and colspans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom-manipulation

I have this table http://codepen.io/MetCastle/pen/lxceL and I want to hide/show the columns depending on an `input type="number"` using jQuery. mean this entire columns:

```
Proveedor 1
Proveedor 2
Proveedor 3
Proveedor 4
Proveedor 5
Proveedor 6
```

I don't know how to do that. I have tried `:nth-child()` Selector, but I don't understand how works.

I made this function but obviously it is incomplete:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($( ".size").val() == 1)
    // hide Proveedor 1
  else if  ($( ".size").val() == 2)
    // hide Proveedor 2

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty flexibly accounting for colspans here... I think this will work for you:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBpxx/): (I put 2 in the `.size` value so you will see it removes the "Proveedor 2" and the columns under it, you can change this in the HTML section of the fiddle to test with different numbers)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var column = 0;
    var colspan;
    $("tr").eq(0).find("th").each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($.trim($this.text()) === "Proveedor "+$(".size").val()) {
            $this.hide();
            colspan = +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
            return false;
        }
        column += +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
    });
    $("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
        var currCol = 0;
        $(this).find("td, th").each(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            if (column === currCol) {
                $this.hide();
                for(i = +$this.attr("colspan") || 1; i < colspan;) {
                    $this = $this.next();
                    $this.hide();
                    i += +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
                }
                return false;
            }
            currCol += +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
        });
    });
});
```

Note:

```
+$this.attr("colspan") || 1
```

The `+` in front is to convert this into a number (from a string). If colspan is undefined it will equate to a falsey value (`NaN`) which will then move on to the `1` (which is the default if `colspan` isn't defined)... so if colspan is defined it will be whatever was defined, otherwise it will be 1.

---

After clarifying some requirements, here is a modification. The code gets pretty complex to deal with both colspans and rowspans....

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBpxx/4/)

```
$(":input").on('change', function () {
    $("td, th").show();
    var column = 0;
    var colspan = 0;
    var rowspanning = [];
    $("tr").eq(0).find("th").each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($.trim($this.text()) === "Proveedor " + $(".size").val()) {
            $this.nextAll().hide();
            colspan = +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
            rowspanning[column] = $this.attr("rowspan")-1 || 0;
            return false;
        }
        column += +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
    });
    if (column) {
        $("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
            var currCol = 0;
            $(this).find("td, th").each(function () {
                $this = $(this);
                if(rowspanning[currCol] > 0) {
                    --rowspanning[currCol];
                    ++currCol;
                }
                rowspanning[currCol] = $this.attr("rowspan")-1 || 0;
                if (column === currCol) {
                    for (i = +$this.attr("colspan") || 1; i < colspan;) {
                        $this = $this.next();
                        i += +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
                    }
                    $this.nextAll().hide();
                    return false;
                }
                currCol += +$this.attr("colspan") || 1;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm sorry, i don't explain what I need,   look, when page load just should appears the first column "Proveedor 1" and if the user change the input type="number" should appears the same columns like the input. I changed the first line for this $(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function ()  [look](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/fK8sn/)

Comment: Ah... you had doc ready... anyway, I'm still not 100% sure I understand, but I think you mean you want the "Proveedor" associated with the number in `.size` to hide whenever `.size` is changed... and everything else to show again... is this what you want now? jsfiddle.net/fK8sn/3

Comment: Sorry but not, if I choose 3 in the input should exist, proveedor 1, proveedor 2 and proveedor 3, y I choose 1 just proveedor 1 and same with others, 5= first 5 columns etc... and I have a question, why dont dissapears the entire column to the bottom? is not posible?
Thanks again

Comment: Having trouble understanding you still... maybe this? http://jsfiddle.net/fK8sn/4/

Comment: Yeah, you're the best men! But i have the same question, why dont dissapears the entire column to the bottom? is not posible, because when you delete the column below oh that column still existing td.

Comment: hmm... i think it might have to do with rowspans which i didn't notice. i don't have time to look at this now as i have a pretty full day ahead of me starting now... but might later today.

Comment: @user3810795, okay so the code starts to get more complicated... but I think I have what you need working... check the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Many thanks @Smerny, you're awesome, I will check your code for understand how works and learn, your support is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:nth-child()` selector to hide the "nth" element after the `tr` element for each row.  For example,

```
  if ($( ".size").val() == 1){
      $('tr td:nth-child(1)').hide();
      //include this line only if you also have a thead element with headings
      $('tr th:nth-child(1)').hide();
  }
  else if ($( ".size").val() == 2){
      $('tr td:nth-child(2)').hide();
      //include this line only if you also have a thead element with headings
      $('tr th:nth-child(2)').hide();
  }
```

Comment: not quite so simple  as just using indexing when colspans are involved